# Vuex getter isn't updating, but not clear how that's possible

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following code, and the darkmode getter updates correctly. The initial state of _darkmode = false.

```
state = { 
    _darkmode: false 
}
```

```js
darkmode: (state) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_DARKMODE) === null) {
      return state._darkmode;
    } else {
      const newDarkmode = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_DARKMODE)
      );
​
      if (state._darkmode) {
        console.log("parsed", newDarkmode);
      } else {
        console.log("parsed", newDarkmode);
      }
​
      return newDarkmode;
    }
  },
```

But the following code results in the getter not being updated:

```js
darkmode: (state) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_DARKMODE) === null) {
      return state._darkmode;
    } else {
      const newDarkmode = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_DARKMODE)
      );
​
      return newDarkmode;
    }
  },
```

I'm clueless on what the "magic" behind this is.

Answer (score 0):

Vuex caches the result of the getter and only will update its value when the dependencies changes.

Here a quote from the docs:

> Vuex allows us to define "getters" in the store. You can think of them as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

Link: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#getters

I think you should update the `_darkmode` value with some action inside your code logic with the value from the localStorage, then the getter will be updated.

Comment: Thx for the pointer. And I read that too. But what I don't understand is if I remove the ```if (state._darkmode) {...``` the getter doesn't update. How does Vue calculate those?

Comment: It happens because there's no state dependecies for vue to check when you remove the `if`. I think it relates to vue's reactivity https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html